# iOS Unicode \u2611 doesn't display on some devices

Tags: ios, unicode

I am displaying a checkbox using the unicode characters `\u2611` and `\u2610` on my iOS app.

On my own device and simulator everything is displaying correctly, however, when I deploy the same app onto another machine's simulator or device, certain devices seem to show the checked character `\u2611` wrongly.

Below is a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

I was suspecting the keyboard, but both the working and non-working seems to be set as British English, so I ruled that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears that all devices on **> iOS 7.1.2** has this problem. It works well on devices running iOS 7.0.2 and lower. Didnt try the rest in between though.

Worked around this by using an image instead of Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of that character changed in iOS 7, so if some of those devices are running older versions of the OS, that could explain it.

[Source - iEmoji.com](http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/527/symbols/ballot-box-with-check)

Comment: all the devices that I tried on are using iOS7. but I havent tried between the minor versions of iOS7 though. shall give that a try.